# Why does the time hierarchy theorem use a rather intricate diagonal argument?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis

Isn't it possible to prove it by defining some problem that can be solved in $f(n)^2$ in the worst case due to its output always being $f(n)^2$ characters so that it won't be solvable in $f(n)$?
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output size does not scale with (time) complexity of problems in general.
In fact, complexity theorists are largely interested in decision problems for which the output will either be 0 or 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "The output size does not scale with (time) complexity of problems in general" Can you expand your answer a bit?

Comment: It's in the second sentence. Complexity theory is largely about decision problems where the output size does not depend on the input size or the running time of an algorithm (if one even exists!). Actually, the wikipedia page for the THT is stated explicitly in terms of decision problems.  What you state in the OP is not wrong, it is just not useful to complexity theorists.

Comment: Do you think that the original paper about the theorem phrased it in terms of decision problems or something similar?

Comment: Yes. Wikipedia gives a reference to the original paper which states the theorem in terms of binary sequences, which are basically decision problems.